# Replacing the filter grayscale (100%) in IE11

Tags: css, svg-filters

I've read that the support for the grayscale(100%) filter  was removed from IE9 and more. Tell me please how can I replace this filter? This filter should be used for .svg format

Comment: please tell us what you want to accomplish and what you tried. This will make helping you easier.

Comment: in your place i will keep the filter and replace IE ... easier ...

Comment: I tried to use this one to apply the filter:

-webkit-filter: grayscale (100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale (100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale (100%);
-o-filter: grayscale (100%);
filter: grayscale (100%);
filter: gray; / * IE 6-9 * /

But it works except IE10 and more. Support for this filter was excluded from IE10, IE11 versions. How can I replace this filter? Apply this filter to me for .svg pictures

Answer (score 0):

IE9 and previous had dxFilters. These were never supported in other browsers and were removed in IE10+.

IE 10/11 do not support CSS-style filters which are now supported in every other browser.

If you want greyscale in these browsers you have to apply the greyscale by adding an SVG greyscale filter INSIDE the .svg file itself (assuming that you're using a normal img tag to include the SVG.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved my problem a little differently, but I was very helpful with your information!